# Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector

Tags: angularjs, backend

This is the first time I have asked a question which I really need an answer to. I'm hoping you folks will generously share some of your answers and insights.

I've been trying to replicate the JavaScript Projects list tutorial on the angularjs.org homepage (the third tutorial from the top of the homepage) in which they have a list which you can add or delete items from, the heading for this tutorial is called 'Wire Up a Backend.' 
   Well, i replicated the lines of code for all of it, line for line, and it does not look like the tutorial's finished product at all. Upon closer inspection, the console logs an error about injection dependencies.
   The code was the same line by line, but it still did not work.
   Here is the code:

index.html:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="project">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-resource.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-route.min.js">
   </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="project.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>JavaScript Projects</h2>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

projects.js:

```
angular.module('project', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])

.value('fbURL', 'https://ng-projects-list.firebaseio.com/')
.service('fbRef', function(fbURL) {
  return new Firebase(fbURL)
})
.service('fbAuth', function($q, $firebase, $firebaseAuth, fbRef) {
  var auth;
  return function () {
      if (auth) return $q.when(auth);
      var authObj = $firebaseAuth(fbRef);
      if (authObj.$getAuth()) {
        return $q.when(auth = authObj.$getAuth());
      }
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      authObj.$authAnonymously().then(function(authData) {
          auth = authData;
          deferred.resolve(authData);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
  }
})

.service('Projects', function($q, $firebase, fbRef, fbAuth, projectListValue) {
  var self = this;
  this.fetch = function () {
    if (this.projects) return $q.when(this.projects);
    return fbAuth().then(function(auth) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var ref = fbRef.child('projects-fresh/' + auth.auth.uid);
      var $projects = $firebase(ref);
      ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.val() === null) {
          $projects.$set(projectListValue);
        }
        self.projects = $projects.$asArray();
        deferred.resolve(self.projects);
      });

      //Remove projects list when no longer needed.
      ref.onDisconnect().remove();
      return deferred.promise;
    });
  };
})

.config(function($routeProvider) {
  var resolveProjects = {
    projects: function (Projects) {
      return Projects.fetch();
    }
  };

  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      controller:'ProjectListController as projectList',
      templateUrl:'list.html',
      resolve: resolveProjects
    })
    .when('/edit/:projectId', {
      controller:'EditProjectController as editProject',
      templateUrl:'detail.html',
      resolve: resolveProjects
    })
    .when('/new', {
      controller:'NewProjectController as editProject',
      templateUrl:'detail.html',
      resolve: resolveProjects
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo:'/'
    });
})

.controller('ProjectListController', function(projects) {
  var projectList = this;
  projectList.projects = projects;
})

.controller('NewProjectController', function($location, projects) {
  var editProject = this;
  editProject.save = function() {
      projects.$add(editProject.project).then(function(data) {
          $location.path('/');
      });
  };
})

.controller('EditProjectController',
  function($location, $routeParams, projects) {
    var editProject = this;
    var projectId = $routeParams.projectId,
        projectIndex;

    editProject.projects = projects;
    projectIndex = editProject.projects.$indexFor(projectId);
    editProject.project = editProject.projects[projectIndex];

    editProject.destroy = function() {
        editProject.projects.$remove(editProject.project).then(function(data) {
            $location.path('/');
        });
    };

    editProject.save = function() {
        editProject.projects.$save(editProject.project).then(function(data) {
           $location.path('/');
        });
    };
});
```

list.html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="projectList.search" class="search-query" id="projects_search"
       placeholder="Search">
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Project</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th><a href="#/new"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></a></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="project in projectList.projects | filter:projectList.search | orderBy:'name'">
    <td><a ng-href="{{project.site}}" target="_blank">{{project.name}}</a></td>
    <td>{{project.description}}</td>
    <td>
      <a ng-href="#/edit/{{project.$id}}"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

detail.html:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: myForm.name.$invalid && !myForm.name.$pristine}">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="editProject.project.name" required>
    <span ng-show="myForm.name.$error.required && !myForm.name.$pristine" class="help-inline">
        Required {{myForm.name.$pristine}}</span>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: myForm.site.$invalid && !myForm.site.$pristine}">
    <label>Website</label>
    <input type="url" name="site" ng-model="editProject.project.site" required>
    <span ng-show="myForm.site.$error.required && !myForm.site.$pristine" class="help-inline">
        Required</span>
    <span ng-show="myForm.site.$error.url" class="help-inline">
        Not a URL</span>
  </div>

  <label>Description</label>
  <textarea name="description" ng-model="editProject.project.description"></textarea>

  <br>
  <a href="#/" class="btn">Cancel</a>
  <button ng-click="editProject.save()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"
          class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
  <button ng-click="editProject.destroy()"
          ng-show="editProject.project.$id" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

This is the error that shows up on the console: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=projectListValueProvider%20%3C-%20projectListValue%20%3C-%20Projects

Please help, I know there are a lot of you that are much more experienced, and I certainly hope I find some answers because I don't have much to turn to, and I've been trying to figure this out for the past couple of days now, so humbly request the help of you veteran coders, and wise sages of the stackoverflow realm.

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: You should click on the error in your console which will open a link with further information about the given error. Seems like a dependency injection is not fulfillable.

Comment: Hey Sajeetharan and albert, thanks for the replies, the comment has been updated with the actual code, it would be much appreciated if you could look at them.

Comment: Did you verify that all of your files have loaded? No 404s?

Comment: I think so. Plus, it's almost identical to the tutorial line by line if you look at the angularjs.org homepage, except theirs works for some reason. This has been taking up so much of my time right now, i would really appreciate your insight James.

Comment: This is the error that shows up on the console: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=projectListValueProvider%20%3C-%20projectListValue%20%3C-%20Projects

Comment: there isn't a tutorial like this on angularjs.org... the only "official" tutorial for angular is the phonecat app.  Are you *sure* this is from angular, and not some other site?  I wanted to compare what you have to the tutorial you keep mentioning, if I could find it....

Comment: @ Claies, Oh it isn't? But it's from angularjs.org, it's the third tutorial from the top that has the title "Wire Up a Backend." Please check it out, and get back to me as I'm really curious now as to why this does not work, Claies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to inject `projectListValue` into your `Projects` service. You never actually define and inject `projectListValue`, and it's breaking when it attempts to get it.

--

The following gets rid of the error, by getting rid of the injection.

```
.service('Projects', function($q, $firebase, fbRef, fbAuth) {
  var self = this;
  this.fetch = function () {
    if (this.projects) return $q.when(this.projects);
    return fbAuth().then(function(auth) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var ref = fbRef.child('projects-fresh/' + auth.auth.uid);
      var $projects = $firebase(ref);
      ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        self.projects = $projects.$asArray();
        deferred.resolve(self.projects);
      });

      //Remove projects list when no longer needed.
      ref.onDisconnect().remove();
      return deferred.promise;
    });
  };
})
```

Comment: sorry to be a bit of a newbie, but how do i manage to fix that in the code? Thanks Dylan...btw StackOverflow is amazing for the relatively quick responses!

Comment: The code expects `projectListValue` to be there but it isn't, the fix would be getting it there. I'm not familiar with the tutorial, but if you're just using an off the shelf project that should just work my guess is that something's missing. Can you link the project you used?

Comment: That's a question for you. Why there's that specific service?

Comment: Mateusz, apologies, but unless you're directing that question to Dylan, it's hard for me to decipher what you mean.

Comment: @Marcode777 See my edit. This should make it "work" insofar as it loads without error. I removed `projectListValue`, which appeared to be used only to set a default value if the firebase ref was null.

Comment: @Dylan Watt, thanks, it did get rid of that error, only to be replaced with another error: [$compile:tpload]. Anyway, I appreciate the help. I know there is a points system on here, how do I give you a point for your rep?

Comment: @Marcode777 Angular has a pretty steep learning curve, because there's a lot of convention you have to have learned to work with it, you can't just brute force it like you usually can with jQuery. The tutorials on  egghead.io were very helpful to me when I was starting with angular. RE: points, there are upvote and accept answer controls to the left of my answer.

Comment: @Dykan Watt, noted on the tutorials. I tried to upvote your answer, but it seems I still don't have the 15 reputation needed yet. Thanks anyway Dylan, you've made my experience asking on stackoverflow a positive one.